# EAN-13 in JavaScript using ESC/POS is not showing the digits below?

Tags: javascript, printing, hex, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to print EAN-13 barcode from a JavaScript application to a thermal printer using ESC/POS command `GS k m d1...dk NUL`.

As per the application specification all commands must go via a Bluetooth plugin using only HEX.

At present, I can print the barcode but it doesn't show the digits below and all of the barcode lines are the same height. I was under the impression that EAN-13 has numbers split into 3 sections with lines of varying heights in between.

**SAMPLE BARCODE:**
6921426623090

**COMMAND:**
`0x1D,0x77,3,0x1D,0x68,160,0x1D,0x6B,2,0x36,0x39,0x30,0x31,0x30,0x32,0x38,0x30,0x37,0x35,0x38,0x33,0x31,00,0x0a,0x0a`

**COMMAND EXPLAINED:**

```
0x1D,0x77,3,   // barcode width
0x1D,0x68,160, // barcode height
0x1D,0x6B,2,0x36,0x39,0x30,0x31,0x30,0x32,0x38,0x30,0x37,0x35,0x38,0x33,0x31,00, // ean-13 barcode: GS k m d1...dkNUL
0x0a,0x0a // space after
```

I am pretty confident it has something to do with my implementation of `GSkmd1...dkNUL`:

```
GS // 0x01D
k  // 0x6B
m  // 2
d1...dk // barcode translated to hex: 0x36,0x39,0x30,0x31,0x30,0x32,0x38,0x30,0x37,0x35,0x38,0x33,0x31
NUL // 00
```

**CURRENT PRINTOUT:**

[image: The current printout]

**DESIRED PRINTOUT:**

[image]

I would appreciate any feedback on how to print the barcode as per the image supplied - with the digits below and lines of varying heights in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not possible to print (non-flat) EAN-13 barcodes using the `print barcode` commands of `ESC/POS`. The only option is to print the image of a non-flat EAN-13 via the `print image` commands of the `ESC/POS`.

Answer (score 0):

These characters are called HRI(Human Readable Interpretation).

A barcode that is not-flat means that the HRI is superimposed on the barcode and printed.

If so, it would be effective to create an image with Bitmap and print it.

Other than this, **I have not tried it, and I do not know whether it is possible**, but it is conceivable to use the page mode to print as follows.

- Enter page mode
- Specify the print range
- Print barcode
- Adjust the print start position
- Overwrite part of the printed barcode with a blank bit image
- Adjust the print start position
- Print a barcode string in the blank area
- Print page mode buffer and exit page mode

**But do you really need a non-flat barcode for such a print layout?**

If it is not necessary to use a non-flat barcode, you can print the barcode and the barcode string simultaneously by the following method.

Please refer to the following.
The corresponding page is in Japanese.
[GS H](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=125)
[GS f](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=126)

GS H n : Select HRI character print position
If you print characters below the barcode, **n** is 0x02 or 0x32.

0x1D 0x48 0x02 or 0x32

GS f n : Select HRI character font
Specify this when you want to change the font of characters printed with the barcode.
The value of **n** will vary depending on the printer.

0x1D 0x66 0x00-0x04 or 0x30-0x34 or 0x61-0x62